# Где должны хранится запросы к БД?

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Да, я знаю, что запросы к БД должны хранится в отдельном слое.

Правильно ли запросы в этом слое писать прямо в коде или их обычно хранят в ресурсах?

Answer (score 7):

Зависит от выбранной архитектуры.

Я весьма рекомендую прочитать книгу "[Руководство Microsoft по проектированию архитектуры приложений, 2-е издание](http://download.microsoft.com/documents/rus/msdn/%D1%80%D1%8B_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0.pdf)", там есть множество советов по проектированию каждого слоя. Ручаюсь - голова кругом пойдёт от многообразия архитектурных паттернов.

Если говорить про слой работы с базой. в современных приложениях чаще встречается вариант динамических запросов ("из кода"), а не хранимых процедур:

> В прошлом хранимые процедуры обеспечивали лучшую производительность по
>   сравнению с динамическими SQL-выражениями. Однако сегодня
>   современные ядра СУБД практически уравняли производительность
>   обработки хранимых процедур и динамических SQL-выражений (использующих
>   параметризованные запросы). Основными факторами при принятии решения
>   об использовании хранимых процедур являются абстракция, удобство
>   обслуживания и среда выполнения.

Из своей практики могу сказать, что да, хранимки использую реже, только когда нужна экстраоптимизация.

Если интересует широта и разнообразие архитектурных подходов к построению слоя работы с базой данных - то вот первая часть таблички:

- Active Record (Активная запись). Включает объект доступа к данным в сущность предметной области.
- Data Mapper (Преобразователь данных). Реализует слой преобразования между объектами и структурой базы данных, используемый для перемещения данных из одной структуры в другую, обеспечивая при этом их независимость.
- Data Transfer Object (Объект передачи данных). Объект, в котором сохраняются данные, передаваемые между процессами, что обеспечивает сокращение необходимого числа вызовов методов.
- Domain Model (Модель предметной области). Набор бизнес-объектов, представляющих сущности предметной области и отношения между ними.
- Query Object (Объект запроса). Объект, представляющий запрос к базе данных.
- Repository (Хранилище). Представление источника данных в памяти, работающее с сущностями предметной области.
- Row Data Gateway (Шлюз записи данных). Объект, выступающий в роли шлюза к отдельной записи источника данных.
- Table Data Gateway (Шлюз таблицы данных). Объект, выступающий в роли шлюза к таблице или представлению источника данных и выполняющий сериализацию всех запросов на выбор, вставку, обновление и удаление.
- Table Module (Модуль таблицы). Единый компонент, реализующий бизнес-логику для всех строк таблицы или представления базы данных.

Узнали какие-то из знакомых подходов? А ведь после таблицы отсылки к книгам Фаулера и отдельная глава 15 ещё раз про базы данных.

Поэтому: в реальных приложениях может быть устроено по-разному. Не надо думать, что если вам тут посоветуют какой-то один подход, то он будет единственно верным.

Answer (score 3):

Правильным с точки зрения масштабируемости и гибкости будет решение, которое не использует SQL напрямую. Лучше использовать ORM, например nhibernate  или entity, реализовать модуль, инкапсулирующий логику взаимодействия с БД в виде отдельного класса(синглтон) и обращаться к нему оттуда, откуда потребуется по заранее определенному контракту, который нужно расширять по мере появления новых задач.

Answer (score 2):

Обычно запросы записывают все со стороны базы, т.е. в процедурах. Но если необходимы именно запросы, то пишут обычно в коде.